# Trying to pass int* to function and to function inside another function.int* was declared in main

Tags: c

IN MAIN
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'calculatetextstatistics' from incompatible pointer type
[Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int **'
   IN CALCULATETEXTSTATISTICS

[Warning] passing argument 2 of 'countwords' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'

What do i do to pass the number of words(n) i calculate from countwords to other function without any warnings?

PROGRAM WORKS AS IT IS (update:BUT WHEN I PASTE IT ON A MAIN (NOT A PROJECT)ERRORS POP UP)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int getchoice(void);
void inserttextfromfile();
void printtextdata(FILE *);
void countwords(FILE *,int *);
void calculatetextstatistics(int *);
void countchars(FILE *);
void countcharsbutspaces(FILE *);
void countuniquewords(FILE *,int* );
void createhistogram(FILE *,int* );
int cntocc(int [],int [],int,int);
int main(){ 
    int a,g;
    int *n=&g;
    while((a=getchoice())){
      switch (a){
            case 1:
                  break;
            case 2:    ;
                  break;
            case 3:    ;
                  break;
            case 4:    ;
                  break;
            case 5:calculatetextstatistics(&n) ;
                  break;
            case 6:    ;
                  break;
            default: break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
int getchoice(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
void calculatetextstatistics(int *n){
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countwords(p,*n);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countchars(p);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countcharsbutspaces(p);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countuniquewords(p,*n);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    createhistogram(p,*n);

}
void countwords(FILE *p,int *n){
    int countw=0;
    char wordholder[10]=" ";
    char wordlist[60][10];
    for (;(fscanf(p,"%s",wordholder))!= EOF;countw++);
    printf("%d\n",countw);
    fclose(p);
    *n=countw;
    return;
}
```

**Whole code (after some corrections)**

NOTICE IN FIRST AND 2 LAST FUNCTIONS I HAVE IN SOME FOR LOOPS *n(just if thats the prob...).

In my project with the state of arguments as above warnings and notes pop up but no errors and programm does what is supposed to do. But if i copy and paste the code on a new main it shows errors (doesn't run) and the code below is the corrected one from main which also doesnt work (does run but doesn't do what it's supposed to do,meaning that it doesnt count the number of words from the file correct and all else is just false.)The real question is how can a program run on project but when i paste it on main it doesnt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int getchoice(void);
void inserttextfromfile();
void printtextdata(FILE *);
void countwords(FILE *,int *);
void calculatetextstatistics(int *);
void countchars(FILE *);
void countcharsbutspaces(FILE *);
void countuniquewords(FILE *,int* );
void createhistogram(FILE *,int* );
int cntocc(int [],int [],int,int);
int main(){ 
    int a,g;
    int *n=&g;
    while((a=getchoice())){
      switch (a){
            case 1:
                  break;
            case 2:    ;
                  break;
            case 3:    ;
                  break;
            case 4:    ;
                  break;
            case 5:calculatetextstatistics(n) ;
                  break;
            case 6:    ;
                  break;
            default: break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
int getchoice(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
//void inserttextfromfile(){
//  FILE *p;
//  p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
//  printtextdata(p);
//  fclose(p);
//  return;
//}
//void printtextdata(FILE *p){
//  int g;
//  char space[10]=" ";
//  for (;(g=fscanf(p,"%s",space))!= EOF;printf("%s\n",space));
//  return;
//}
void calculatetextstatistics(int *n){
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countwords(p,n);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countchars(p);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countcharsbutspaces(p);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countuniquewords(p,n);
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    createhistogram(p,n);

}
void countwords(FILE *p,int *n){
    int countw=0;
    char wordholder[10]=" ";
    char wordlist[60][10];
    for (;(fscanf(p,"%s",wordholder))!= EOF;countw++);
    printf("%d\n",countw);
    fclose(p);
    *n=countw;
    return;
}
```

Comment: `n` is already a pointer, you shouldn't not be using the addresof (`&`) operator to pass it into your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one problem:

The function `calculatetextstatistics` expects a `int*` but you call it with a `int**` in `main`.

Here

```
int *n=&g;   // n is a int*

....

case 5:calculatetextstatistics(&n) ; // Here you take address-of and making it int**
```

So just do

```
case 5:calculatetextstatistics(n) ;
```

The next problem is very similar:

```
countwords(p,*n);  // Since n is int* then *n is an int
```

But `countwords` expects an `int*`

So just do

```
countwords(p,n);
```

The same seem to apply to

```
countuniquewords(p,*n);
```

and

```
createhistogram(p,*n);
```

Comment: now i get [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: and 7 [Note] initializing argument 2 of 'void countwords(FILE*, int*)'

Comment: How about this `countuniquewords(p,*n);`  and `createhistogram(p,*n);` ? They shall also be changed

Answer (score 0):

Focus on one function at a time, so comment out the remaining functions 1 at a time to make sure you understand where the error is. I'm also not sure if you aren't allowed to use `while` loops for some reason but the way you read the file is a bit odd to me so I changed that in this answer.

```
void calculatetextstatistics(int *n){
   FILE *p;
   p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
   countwords(p,n);
   rewind(p);
   countchars(p);
   rewind(p);
   countcharsbutspaces(p);
   rewind(p);
#if 0
   countuniquewords(p,n);
   rewind(p);
   createhistogram(p,n);
#endif
   fclose(p);
}
void countwords(FILE *p,int *n){
   int countw=0;
   char wordholder[10]=" ";
   char wordlist[60][10];
//   for (;(fscanf(p,"%s",wordholder))!= EOF;countw++);
   while (fscanf(p,"%s",wordholder) != EOF) {
      countw++;
   }
   printf("Number of words: %d\n",countw);
   *n=countw;
   return;
}
void countchars(FILE *p){
   char ch;
   int countc=0;
   while (fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF) {
      if (ch != '\n')
         countc++;
   }
   printf("Number of characters: %d\n",countc);
}
void countcharsbutspaces(FILE *p){
   char ch;
   int countcbs=0;
//    for(;(fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF);countcbs++,countcbs-=(ch==' '));
   while (fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF) {
      if (ch != '\n' && ch != ' ')
         countcbs++;
   }
   printf("Number of Characters w/o Spaces: %d\n",countcbs);
}
```

Also when you ask a question on SO you don't want to just say "it doesn't do what it's supposed to do" because that's kind of obvious and doesn't help us help you at all. You should provide an example of the text file "mytext.txt". For this I just made a text file containing "one two three four" and it prints

Number of words: 4

Number of characters: 18

Number of Characters w/o Spaces: 15

Probably doesn't matter for this as it seems like homework but you don't need to keep opening and closing the file.

Open it once, then after each function call `rewind(p);` or `fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);` then call the next function. Then close the file at the end when you're done with it. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i made a text with 2 lines and it prints the correct results.

Comment: @Tyler it depends if you were trying to count the newline character `\n` as a character or not

Comment: There is a newline character at the end of each line in that text file. So if you didn't know that then maybe that's why you thought you were getting incorrect results.

Comment: will try it.just need to figure somthing with my histogram